# Ruby on Rail - Create a folder and .txt file when create new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, directory

I am building a application where **companies** can add many **domains** under their account.

What I want to achieve is: When a domains is `created`, in my `public/domains` folder I want to create a **new folder** with **folder name** => `domain id` and add a `.txt` file with same naming convention.

Example:

```
Public // This is public folder in Rails
  --- domains
        ---- 2 // This is domain ID
             --- 2.txt
```

What I have now:

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  def create_folder
    dir = Dir.mkdir("#{Rails.root}/public/domains/#{self.id}")
    file = File.dirname("#{Rails.root}/public/domains/#{self.id}/#{self.id}.txt")
  end
end
```

This does create the folder but doesn't creates the `.txt` file.

Comment: Why do you want to generate that file in `public` and not deliver a text response from a controller?

Comment: And what is the problem? What have you tried? What worked differently from your expectations? (Btw based on your question, you will probably be introducing a security vulnerability. What you described doesn't sound like a good idea.)

Comment: Im going to use that folder for some uses that Im going to have outside of the application.

Comment: Reason I have this is that, websites get a `.js` file they include to `<head></head>` and one function we have is we count *hits* that file get. So instead of adding thousands impressions each second, we add impressions to that file and every 5 min, we add them to `hits table`. Thats the idea. any other way out there instead of doing this?

Comment: can you show the rest of the domain model? Also what system does this have to work on?

Comment: Thats the whole mode. what you mean by which system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File.dirname` does not create a file.

You want:

```
filename = Rails.root.join("/public/domains/#{id}/#{id}.txt")

File.open(filename, 'wb') do |file|
  file << "My content"
  file << "More content"
end
```

Be sure to create the directory before

As for your use case:

Don't use a file. Don't store it public. Use Redis or similar if needed. But first just try if your DB can't cope with the load. Or did you try and hit a limit?

Be aware that everything in **/public** is **public** which means that one can access it through your webserver.

A non Rails example:

```
require 'fileutils'
id = 123
filename = "/tmp/public/domains/#{id}/#{id}.txt"
FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(filename))
File.open(filename, 'wb') do |file|
  file << "My content"
  file << "More content"
end
```

Comment: Thanks @pascal. No I haven't hit a limit but Im afraid if it gets thousands of views each sec, it will make some issues. Could you please tell how Redis does that?

Comment: If you will get thousands of views each second then you have a nice problem:-). And perhaps there are other solutions to your question.
Redis (and others) is a in memory data store. You could increment an integer for each visit. Then every X minutes/seconds you can issue a single update to your DB and reset the counter. 

But I'd just go with the easy solution first and do some benchmarking.

Comment: Yeah thats the idea behind what I was trying to do. That each visit gets registered to that files and every min or so, it send a single line to database. Tnx for help :)

Comment: I tried with your code and files still not created. I also got error: `undefined local variable filename `

Comment: well, assign `filename` the desired filename as a string. Updated sample.

Comment: Thanks, @pascal. But still doesn't create the `.txt` file. I got error that says `public/domains/18/18.txt doesn't exist` like it tries to open it and not add `18.txt`

Comment: Did you create the directory? You probably need to use `mkdir_p` so it creates the directories for the full path. Added a non-rails sample.

Comment: Thanks @pascal Will give a try now